# How should I protect the sensitive content in my iOS app from screenshots?

Tags: ios, screenshot

Is there any possible way to make a blur ViewController in iOS when a user tries to take a screenshot?

Or any option that executes a function before the screenshot is saved?

Comment: I'm looking for execute function before screenshot is saved.

Comment: And that question and comments answer your question - it is not possible

Comment: I find paid possibility like https://screenshieldkit.com/, but I'm looking for any open source?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/177585/how-does-ios-screenshot-prevention-screenshield-by-confide-work-under-the-hood

Comment: And that doesn't even work anymore: since iOS 7 taking screenshot doesn't cancel touches.

Comment: _ScreenShieldKit’s patent-pending technology (...)_ - what exactly do they expect to patent? Using publicly available APIs? That sounds like load of marketing mumbo-jumbo

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but even if there was one, this doesn't prevent users from taking pictures of the screen so it doesn't protect the data all that much.

Answer (score 1):

What you want cannot be achieved using any public APIs. In older iOS versions it was possible to rely on touching the screen to show sensitive information, but since iOS 7 taking screenshot no longer cancels touches.

Relying on observing `NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot` notification is also out of the question, since that notification is posted after the screenshot is taken, not before - it follows iOS naming convention with `DidTake` statement, and there is no `WillTake` equivalent of this notification.

The solution linked in comment - [ScreenShieldKit](https://screenshieldkit.com/) - also seem to be useless, since [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/177585/how-does-ios-screenshot-prevention-screenshield-by-confide-work-under-the-hood) on Information Security subforum claims it indeed relies on canceling touches which, as mentioned before, no longer works.

At any rate: no, currently there is no known way to prevent screenshots from being taken, using publicly available APIs.